# how to create days from time delta

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I get an error when trying to convert a time delta column to a string containing the number od fays.

```
from datetime import datetime

d = {'col1':[datetime.strptime('2020-1-1', '%Y-%m-%d'),datetime.strptime('2020-1-2', '%Y-%m-%d')],
     'col2':[datetime.strptime('2020-1-5', '%Y-%m-%d'),datetime.strptime('2020-1-10', '%Y-%m-%d')]}


d = pd.DataFrame(d)

d['days']=d['col2']-d['col1']

df
```

This code works with this example but it doesn`t work on my real problem, giving me the following error:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'days'

```
days_number = []

for i in range(len(d)):
    aux = df['days'][i].days
    days_number.append(aux)

   
df['days']=days_number
```

It also works fine with this lambda function on my example but not in my real problem

```
df['days'] = df['days'].apply(lambda x: x.days)
```

Object type in example and real problem are the same

```
type(df['days'])
type(df['days'][1])
```

these are the types of my real example:
pandas.core.series.Series
pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta

I am sorry I can`t reproduce the real example in which I am getting the error but maybe someone knows why this error is happening

Appreciate

Comment: Use `d['days']=(d['col2']-d['col1']).dt.days`

Comment: also, it might be easier to use `pd.to_datetime`, e.g. as `pd.to_datetime(['2020-1-1', '2020-1-2'])`